# Best way to block users from connecting to VOIP (Teamspeak)

Tags: blocking, voip, teamspeak

In a teamspeak that I work with, we've banned users from comming back and they just change their IP and come back on. We've been searching for a way to keep them out even if they change their IP. Do any of you know any good methods?

Also I was stuck between posting this in Superuser or Server fault since I didn't think this belong in Server fault. Thank you!

Comment: There is a mention on TeamSpeak 3 to ban based on "Unique ID" perhaps you can check if that particular user has a Unique ID (regardless of IP address) that you can ban? (Sorry I don't use TeamSpeak so I can't test this) Ref: http://wiki.enjin.com/wiki/TeamSpeak_3#Ban_Manager

Comment: Not knowing TeamSpeak very well, but is there perhaps a way to ban user accounts? Maybe the best way is to get voice recognition software and ban on that basis.